# Loading a package from a VCS repository not working

Tags: json, git, composer-php

I am trying to use a personal repository with modified code of someone elses repository on GitHub.

I did exactly what [getcomposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository) said by adding `repositories` in `composer.json`.

Whenever I `composer update` though, I check the code and it's always the original one instead of mine.

This is my `composer.json`.

```
{
    [...]
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/GiampaoloFalqui/php-phantomjs"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/GiampaoloFalqui/tesseract-ocr-for-php"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "codesleeve/asset-pipeline": "dev-master",
        "jonnyw/php-phantomjs": "3.*",
        "thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr": ">= 0.2.0"
    },
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by branching the code in a branch that is not `master` and by adding `dev-` followed by the branch name in the `composer.json` (in my case `bugfix`), like this:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "codesleeve/asset-pipeline": "dev-master",
    "jonnyw/php-phantomjs": "dev-bugfix",
    "thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr": "dev-bugfix"
},
```